# Function that returns only whitespaces and letters

Tags: c, function, char, definition, c-strings

I'm trying to write an function that with given char string, returns the same string but w/o nothing except letters and whitespaces.

I nearly nailed it, but I'm stuck with removing symbols like ".", "/" and so on.

Here is already running code but with issue I just describe.

```
char* zastap(const char *napis) {
    char* jeden = napis;
    char* dwa = napis;
    while (*jeden) {
        if(isdigit(*dwa)) {
            dwa++;
            continue; }
        *jeden++ = *dwa++;
    }
    *jeden = '/0';
    return napis;
}
```

Oh btw, it have to be made in this form - I mean "char* zastap(const char *napis) "

I would love if someone could show me the correct way to solve this. It's very basic conditional in a loop I guess, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Does your compiler complain about a multi-character constant? (it should)

Comment: `'/0'` should be `'\0'`.  That's not your main problem, though.

Comment: If you want letters and spaces, shouldn't you use `isalpha()` and `isspace()` (or perhaps `isblank()`)?  There are other non-letters than just the digits!

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function is declared incorrectly. It should be declared like

```
char * zastap( char *napis );
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise the declaration confuses users of the function. They will think that the function creates a copy of the original string.

Instead of the check with the function `isdigit` you should use a check with functions `isalpha` and `isblank` and if a character satisfies these functions then write it in the result string.

Within the function this loop statement

```
while (*jeden)
```

has an invalid condition.

It seems you mean

```
while (*dwa)
```

The terminating zero character is `'\0'` not `'/0'`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * zastap( char *napis ) 
{
    char *p = napis, *q = napis;

    do
    {
        if ( !*q || isalpha( ( unsigned char )*q ) || isblank( ( unsigned char )*q ) )
        {
            *p++ = *q;
        }
    } while ( *q++ );

    return napis;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char napis[] = "2019Alek Lucek Kamiński2019";

    puts( napis );
    puts( zastap( napis ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2019Alek Lucek Kamiński2019
Alek Lucek Kamiski
```

You may substitute this statement in the if statement inside the loop

```
*p++ = *q;
```

for these statements

```
if ( p != q ) *p = *q;
++p;
```

Comment: Unclear why code has `!*q ||` as the _null character_ is not an alpha nor a blank.